# How to migrate our Test Platforms to our already Published App?

Tags: facebook, submit, integration-testing

We want to publish our new game on Android. This game uses Facebook login, FB Game Services and 2 permissions: publish_actions and user_games_activity.
We need to submit Open graph actions and all our permissions before publishing this game on Google Play. After that our app will have a right to use these permissions and OG for all our further platforms such as Canvas and iOS.
We are going to develop Canvas and iOS platforms with the same FB game services as Android has. But to develop and test them, we must use Test App to avoid their accessibility to all users.

So, we will get the Test App ID and Test App Secret after creating Test App. These IDs differ from our published app. It means that all Open Graph Actions and Objects (e.g. Achievements, Pass, Celebrate Victory) will use the test IDs to enable us to test them. Here is an example of XML-node where we use the Facebook app IDs.

After development and testing our test version with Test App IDs, the Test IDs must be substituted by the IDs of our published app. As we have Achieve (Action Type) Game Achievement (Object) and Celebrate (Action Type) Victory (Object) and the number of our achievements is about 50 and victory objects are about 150, then the problem appears with replacing of all these IDs. It will be at least 200 places where we must change the IDs.

So, the questions are:

1) Can we use the IDs of the published app in the open graph and wherever needed?

What if we implemented some additional OG actions and add the other permission, for example, user_groups or user_posts.
To submit them we will need to add Facebook Canvas platform to our existing Published App with already approved publish_action, user_games_activity permissions and OG Actions. And users won't be able to use them. And we'll have to wait for at least 1 week for our app to work properly due to necessity of approval new added permissions and OG Actions.

2) What should be done in this case? Is there any way to get approval for new permissions and OG Actions before adding FB canvas or other platform in the list of platforms to our already Published App and making it available to all users?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you're using the ID of published app in?

Comment: Hello  Shireesh, 
Thank you a lot for your reply! I realy appreciate it!
Currently we don't have such app. But we are going to publish Facebook app with ID 1510577635883406 (it is in development mode) with Android Platform and then we are going to add Facebook Canvas and IOS Platform. For this case we created the Test App (ID 1592413021033200) to test these platforms while the Android platform is live.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what exact issue you're describing here with production vs test app. Are you submitting the test app for review and want to use it on the production app? Some more explanation on the exact issue here will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: We will have Live (Public) Facebook App with Android Platform and with submitted OG Actions and permissions. To add Facebook Canvas Platform first we must create Test App and use Test App ID and Test App Secret. To migrate from Test to Public App, we must replace Test App IDs in all XML-nodes: <meta property="fb:app_id" content=" OUR APP ID" / (we have about 200 XML-nodes with IDs to be replaced). After replacing to Public IDs, we have to test the Facebook Canvas which has to be already public. Can we use ID of the published app in the OG and wherever needed instead of Test App ID?

Comment: Yes I think you can use that. I'm assuming you're asking w.r.t submitting for review?

Comment: 1. The app will be public and OG Actions, public_actions, user_games_activity permissions will be approved.  
2.The App will have Android platform, while FB Canvas and iOS App are scheduled for later.
3. To develop simultaneously Canvas App, we must create Test App and use Test ID
4. Regarding your answer that we can use Public ID. How we can implement it? To use Public ID, we have to add Platform to public app. But in this case Canvas app will be available to all users. However users will get errors while playing game on Facebook, because Canvas App will be only in development and TEST mode.

Comment: Hello Shireesh,
Have you understood what our problem is?
Do you need any other information or clarification from our side?

Comment: Hey Victoria,

Sorry for missing your previous comment. But I get your issue on why you need a test app to not release your canvas app to public. 

Now the next question I have is about what specific features / permissions do you want to get approved on your test app? Can you give an example of how the workflow will look like so I understand your pain point better. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Shireesh, 
Thanks a ton for your assistance! 
Regarding adding special features to our app. What if the new permissions is added to our FB Canvas Platform . For example, user_posts, user_groups or All Mutual Friends API
And my first question still remains: is there any way to use the publiс App ID in our Test App or any other solution of our problem with replacing IDs in XML-nodes? Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: Hi Shireesh, 
Hope you are doing well! I am looking forward to hearing from you!